# Three.js: Video Texture on Skybox

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

Can someone help with videotexture on cube in three.js with WebGLRenderer.
I am trying to use Three.js to render a cube with one-piece videotexture from one file without use

```
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube
```

instead image such as jpg, but I don't get visible cubes. Should ideally i need create something like 180 degrees half sphere video panorama but only with cube. That is, i want to put a texture to all faces of a cube, not cutting it, in the one stream because if I use different video textures on every face then this will affect the performance.

I am trying to use video texture on sphere like here

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html

and all works fine, but i want use cube like here

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_refraction.html

but I don't get visible cubes.

I don't want to cut a movie file to six different parts to put them on every face of the cube as in this example.
Maybe other methods to overlay material on cube form one video file than using different textures for each face?

Thx and sorry for my english.

Comment: If I understand, you want to create a cube skybox with each face being a video texture. But for performance reasons, you want to have only a single video stream, instead of six separate video streams. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But ideally I would like to it was only half of the cube without a single face from behind. In the example of the sphere to the texture was half-sphere i used it
    texture.repeat.set( 2, 1 )

Comment: Interesting. I have not seen what you want done. Perhaps you should change your title to "Three.js: Video Texture on Skybox".